# Cursores y ListIterator de Java en C#

Tags: c#

En C# no hay cursores como en Java

1. Enumeración
2. iterador
3. ListIterator

En vez de ellos se utiliza la IEnumerable y IEnumerator. Quisiera saber si estos cursores en Java tienen alguna equivalencia en C# así como los métodos de ListIterator como por ejemplo
listiterator.hasprevious().

Gracias.

Comment: Este sitio es oro puro: https://www.dotnetperls.com/s#c# Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx. Muchas gracias. Es oro como bien dices.

Comment: C# es muy poderoso, cosa de saberlo estudiar y saber elegir lugares de dónde aprender, éxitos bro :D

Comment: @fredyfx. Si no es molestia. Me podrías recomendar algún sitio de Estructura de datos en C#. (Listas enlazadas, Colas, Pilas, y árboles)

Comment: Para estructuras en sí: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/ y orientado a C#: https://cis300.cs.ksu.edu/stacks-queues/ -> aquí también hay teoría y algo de práctica.

Comment: @fredyfx.  Mil gracias me has salvado un semestre.

Comment: Para servirles, masbien es gracias a Google y Ecosia.org que indexaron ese contenido "C# linked list queue stack tree". Saludos :D

Comment: Dato adicional: https://github.com/aalhour/C-Sharp-Algorithms ahora sí, a practicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C# tienes la interfaz [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) que te permite recorrer el arreglo por medio de un [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator). Es necesario que una clase implemente `IEnumerable` para poder usarla en un [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement).

`IEnumerator` es más simple que su contraparte en Java.

La función `MoveNext` intenta avanzar al siguiente elemento. Si lo logra devuelve `true`, sino `false`.

La función `Reset` vuelve a su posición inicial (antes del primer elemento).

La propiedad `Current` te permite leer el elemento en la posición actual.

---

Podrías recorrer un arreglo (implementa la interfaz) de la siguiente manera:

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var it = numeros.GetEnumerator(); 
while (it.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(it.Current);


// O con foreach
foreach (int n in numeros)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

---

Para recorrer hacia atrás un `IEnumerable` puedes usar la función [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse) de [`Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Cambiando el ejemplo de antes:

```
var it = numeros.Reverse().GetEnumerator(); 
while (it.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(it.Current);


// O con foreach
foreach (int n in numeros.Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

No olvides agregar `using System.Linq` al inicio del archivo.

Si estas opciones no se ajustan a tus necesidades, puedes escribir tus propias funciones y estructuras.

Comment: Agradecido. Pero, ¿Cómo es que implemento en C# listiterator.hasprevious() de java?